# How install vagrant 2.2.0 on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, vagrant

I have problem from install vagrant on ubuntu 18.04.

I download vagrant 2.2.0 => install his.

But have error run vagrant up

> ```
> > ==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...  /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:128:in
> > `block in identities': can't modify frozen NilClass (RuntimeError) 
> > from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:122:in
> > `times'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:122:in
> > `identities' from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:104:in
> > `each_identity'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:19:in
> > `authenticate'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:85:in
> > `block in authenticate'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:71:in
> > `each'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:71:in
> > `authenticate'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:246:in
> > `start'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/vagrant-2.2.0/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:415:in
> > `block (2 levels) in connect'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:93:in `block in
> > timeout'  from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:33:in
> > `block in catch'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:33:in `catch'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:33:in `catch'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:108:in `timeout'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/vagrant-2.2.0/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:389:in
> > `block in connect'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/vagrant-2.2.0/lib/vagrant/util/retryable.rb:17:in
> > `retryable'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/vagrant-2.2.0/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:388:in
> > `connect'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/vagrant-2.2.0/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:84:in `block in wait_for_ready'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:93:in `block in
> > timeout'  from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:33:in
> > `block in catch'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:33:in `catch'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:33:in `catch'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:108:in `timeout'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/vagrant-2.2.0/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:62:in `wait_for_ready'  from
> > /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.0/gems/vagrant-2.2.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/wait_for_communicator.rb:16:in
> > `block in call'
> ```

"Vagrant up --debug" ends the same way.
I tried to put the gems separately, but it does not help.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: this seems to be non-vagrant issue:https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues/479

Comment: I install ruby-net-ssh, dut it not work too.

Comment: Your issee is probably occurring before the output you displayed above.

Answer (score 3):

To confirm whether you have `vagrant` installed or not, run

```
$ vagrant --version
```

Personally check for the latest available developer version (as mentioned), consider [HashiCorp Downloads](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html). Find one appropriate for your OS.

**Install Vagrant on Ubuntu 18.04**

Install `virtualbox` which allows you to run an OS on top of another OS by creating a virtual OS

```
$ sudo apt install virtualbox
```

Look for any updates before downloading `vagrant`:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ curl -O https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.10/vagrant_2.2.10_x86_64.deb
```

Note: You can get the version you want by replacing `2.2.10` to `2.2.x`. This will download the version (or latest version) after checking the downloads page.

Once the `.deb` is downloaded, install `vagrant` by running:

```
$ sudo apt install ./vagrant_2.2.10_x86_64.deb
```

Again, making sure that you look at the version you downloaded earlier (`2.2.x`)

**Verify vagrant installation**

```
$ vagrant --version
```

**Getting started with Vagrant**

```
$ mkdir my_new_project
$ cd my_new_project
```

Next, initialize a new Vagrantfile using `vagrant init` and specify the box you want to use. Boxes are the package format for the Vagrant environments and are provider-specific. You can find a list of publicly available Vagrant Boxes on the [Vagrant box catalog page](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=downloads&provider=&q=Ubuntu%2018.04).

```
$ vagrant init ubuntu/bionic64
```

Better still, while within your project directory, you can create a `VagrantFile` and add vagrant configurations there as follows:

```
$ touch Vagrantfile
```

Your configurations, specifying your preferred box (and, by extension) your IP:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "x.x.x.x"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.memory =  '1024'
    end
end
```

Run the `vagrant up` command to create and configure the virtual machine as specified in the vagrant file:

```
$ vagrant up
```

Vagrant also mounts the project directory at `/vagrant` in the virtual machine which allows you to work on your project’s files on your host machine.To ssh into the virtual machine, run:

```
$ vagrant ssh
```

You can stop the virtual machine with the following command:

```
$ vagrant halt
```

Terminally, you can stop the machine from running and destroy all the resources created using:

```
$ vagrant destroy
```

**Uninstall vagrant**

If at one point you would like to uninstall `vagrant`, you can run these commands (adding `sudo` privileges if you'd want):

```
$ rm -rf /opt/vagrant
$ rm -f /usr/bin/vagrant
```

Check for successful uninstall:

```
$ which vagrant
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem fix.
Found a solution to the problem in this issue https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10119

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `vagrant` gem by doing `gem uninstall vagrant` after that you should install it system wide, in ubuntu you can download your `deb` file from
https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html
After successful installation of vagrant you can use command `vagrant init hashicorp/precise64` to create a VegrantFile which contains information about your Virtual Machine.

Now boot-up your VM through vagrant by running `vagrant up`, if you want to ssh then type `vagrant ssh`.

P.S. I am using Ubuntu 18.04, please make sure you will not get into trouble after gem uninstall.